# cordova-plugin-local-notification not working smallIcon, vibrate, sound

Tags: cordova, audio, localnotification

Please help me to find out how to make Cordova play my own sound instead of a default when my app notifies users.
I use this code:

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        title: 'Some title',  
        text: 'Some text',  
        smallIcon: 'file://img/small.png',  //it doesn't work
        icon: 'file://img/icon.png',        // it works
        vibrate: true,                      //it doesn't work
        sound: "file://sounds/message.mp3", //it doesn't work
    });
```

Can anybody help me in solving the problem with smallIcon, vibrate and sound?